# OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener not working on all devices?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, listener, preferences

In my onCreate void, I use this to check if a preference has been changed :

```
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener listener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
            Log.d(TAG, "PREFERENCES CHANGED : " + key);
        }
    };
    preferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);
```

It works perfectly on my Nexus 6 (5.1.1) but not (never display log message) on my Samsung tablet tab S2 (5.0.2).

Is it due to the Android version ?

Comment: Works on my Samsung SM-P900 with Android 5.0.2... that should be pretty close to your S2.

Comment: I confirm that on mys Nexus 6, onSharedPreferenceChanged is called and Log message is displayed, but on my tablet Samsung Galaxy Tab S2, onSharedPreferenceChanged is never called (and Log never displayed)...

Comment: I'm going to test on different devices with genymotion... anyway, thx for your answer...

Answer (score 1):

`Is it due to the Android version ?`

[Documentation states that no. It has been present since API 1](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.html)

> public abstract void onSharedPreferenceChanged (SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key)
>   Added in API level 1
>
> Called when a shared preference is changed, added, or removed. This may be called even if a preference is set to its existing value.
>
> This callback will be run on your main thread.
>   Parameters
>   sharedPreferences   The SharedPreferences that received the change.
>   key     The key of the preference that was changed, added, or removed.

However, also note:

> Caution:
>
> > The preference manager does not currently store a strong reference to the listener. You must store a strong reference to the listener, or it will be susceptible to garbage collection. We recommend you keep a reference to the listener in the instance data of an object that will exist as long as you need the listener.

Comment: Thx, so I don't understand why onSharedPreferenceChanged is not called when I execute my app on Samsung tablet, and working fine on my smartphone ??? The only difference is also that my app requires SMS permisson and on my tablet there is no 3G, but I cannot imagine it's the reason !

Comment: I have tested my app on several devices with Genymotion... For all Android versions before 5.1.0, onSharedPreferenceChanged is not called when I change a setting in preference. In 5.1.0 and latest versions, it's called. So my question becomes "what is the alternative to onSharedPreferenceChanged for earlier versions of Android ?"... Thx

Comment: Are you using commit or apply to perform the changes? Also, I use `onSharedPreferenceChanged` on API 19, and it works corrrectly

Comment: getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new MyPreferenceFragment()).commit();

Comment: The GC idea is interesting. You can try changing your listener into a field of whichever activity you're in, to make sure it was not garbage collected. It'll be easier to monitor if it's still there (just put a breakpoint anywhere and go through your fields). There were a lot of changes to garbage collection in Lollipop, and that might explain the issue.